# Feature test error - uninitialized constant FFaker::File

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, tdd, faker

This is my feature spec test for creating a new post

```
require 'rails_helper'
require 'ffaker'

RSpec.feature 'Creating posts', :type => :feature do
  scenario 'can create a new post' do
    visit root_path
    click_link 'New Post'
    attach_file('Image', FFaker::File.file_name('spec/files', 'foo', 'jpg'))
    fill_in 'Caption', with: 'Hello World! This is the first post!'
    click_button 'Create Post'
    expect(page).to have_content('Post was successfully created')
  end
end
```

When I run the `rspec` command to run the test I get the following error

```
Failure/Error: attach_file('Image', FFaker::File.file_name('spec/files', 'foo', 'jpg'))

NameError:
       uninitialized constant FFaker::File
```

How can I fix this?

Basically I htought to use `ffaker` for trying to upload an image instead of using a real image file. Is this supposed to work with ffaker, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error tells you that Rails can't find `FFaker::File` module. FFaker gem [reference](https://github.com/ffaker/ffaker/blob/master/REFERENCE.md) tells me that there's actually no `FFaker::File` module in FFaker.

But there is one in [Faker](https://github.com/stympy/faker) (`Faker::File`). And since FFaker is just refactored Faker I believe you can use Faker for your needs.

Comment: Oh, I see.. how can I use FFaker for images in this case then?

Comment: @Lykos, don't know. How did you use it for images? Anyway I can't find `FFaker::File` in FFaker source code as well.

Comment: No, what I meant was whether there's an alternative way in FFaker to use for having a fake image, or do I have to use a real image file in my test. The only this I've found closest to FFaker::File is `FFaker::Avatar`

Comment: Isn't it acceptable for you to use Faker instead of FFaker?